# why ss round to nearest minute that will change day

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, rounding

I am using sql server 2008 R2 and due to one problem i am able to know that smalldatetime round ss to nearest minute . here is content from MSDN .

**`ss is two digits, ranging from 00 to 59, that represent the second. Values that are 29.998 seconds or less are rounded down to the nearest minute, Values of 29.999 seconds or more are rounded up to the nearest minute.`**

Now i face one problem due to this, that i have parameter type in my `storedproceduer` is smalldatetime when i pass `'2014-03-23 23:59:59'` its converted to date `2014-03-24 00:00:00`

I found the solution that i should convert parameters from `smalldatetime` to `nvarchar(30)`

and problem solved.

but my real question why such behavior of `smalldatetime` rounding of **`ss`** that change the day ?

you can try it with following queries

```
DECLARE @EndDate smallDatetime
SET @EndDate = '2014-03-23 23:59:59'
SELECT @EndDate

DECLARE @EndDate smallDatetime
SET @EndDate = '2014-03-23 23:59:30'
SELECT @EndDate

DECLARE @EndDate smallDatetime
SET @EndDate = '2014-03-23 23:59:29'
SELECT @EndDate
```

Comment: Almost certainly, if you're working with date *and* time data, you'll find things a lot easier to work with if you start storing/working with the end date as an *exclusive* datetime value, rather than *inclusive*. That is, rather than doing `ValueToCheck <= @EndDate`, do `ValueToCheck < @EndDate`. The end date values that you need in such a situation are usually far easier to calculate (and you don't need to change them if you later change from `smalldatetime` to `datetime` or `datetime2`, where the time is stored with different precisions. In such a case, `20140324` is the end value you need.

Answer (score 5):

Alarm bells go off in my head any time I see someone using `23:59:59` in SQL.

This is almost always because they want to return a full days worth of data in the query by doing something like:

```
WHERE  date_field BETWEEN '2014-03-19 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-19 23:59:59'
```

This is because `BETWEEN` includes the boundary values and you might not want values at `2014-03-20 00:00:00` included.

The above query is equivalent to:

```
WHERE  date_field >= '2014-03-19 00:00:00'
AND    date_field <= '2014-03-19 23:59:59'
```

### The Correct Approach

```
WHERE  date_field >= '2014-03-19 00:00:00'
AND    date_field <  '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
```

Notice the subtle difference in the operators.

Answer (score 3):

Because that is the nearest minute.

Given it is defined as rounding up at 29.998 seconds or above, what other result would you expect? At 23:58:30, you expect it to round to 23:59 - why should the behaviour be any different a minute later?

If you want a more precise date/time measurement, use `datetime`, or `datetime2` - not `nvarchar`