# Difference in display of dateofbirth field between system and database

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run the following query in the database(MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
SELECT
    FullName 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    BirthDate 
FROM ClientDetails
WHERE
convert(datetime, BirthDate) = Convert(datetime, '1962/06/16')
```

I don't get any results back from the database BUT when I search by combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` using this query:

```
SELECT
    FullName 
    FirstName, 
    LastName,
    BirthDate 
FROM ClientDetails
WHERE  FirstName = 'F' AND LastName = 'Paro'
```

I get the following results:

```
"V Vusumzi" "Mtim" "***1962-06-15 22:00:00.000***"
```

In the application where this record can be viewed, the date is displayed as: `"1962/06/16"`

Question is, why are the dates different?
In fact all records have a single digit difference in the day part of the date.

Comment: As the time on that date is 10pm, it could be a different day in a different timezone.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the application"? Are you looking at this data in an external tool?

Comment: What is the data type of the `BirthDate` field? As you are converting it to `datetime` that would suggest that it's not a `datetime` field, so why isn't it?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, its an external tool but I have access to the database from which the data is retrieved from.

Comment: @Guffa: It's a datetime type

Comment: If you access the db directly, what does the date look like?

Comment: @Andrew I get this exactly: '1962-06-15 22:00:00.000'

Comment: What does the application do with the date? Does it convert from UTC to local time, or the opposite?

Comment: If you run your query with `convert(datetime, BirthDate) = Convert(datetime, '1962/06/15')`, do you get back the expected row?  It sounds like your presentation app is converting the date, or maybe rounding it?

Answer (score 1):

Because `Convert(datetime, '1962/06/16')` is implicitly converted to midnight, and `1962-06-16 00:00:00` is not the same datetime as `1962-06-15 22:00:00.000`.

If you don't care about the time portion, and just want to compare the date convert both sides of the predicate to `DATE`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, BirthDate) = CONVERT(DATE, '1962-06-16')
```

If you do care about the time portion then your query is working as expected.

N.B. Be wary using culture specific formats when using literals for dates, e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '1962/06/16')
```

May work fine for you, but someone whose regional settings differ may get an invalid cast, e.g.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '1962/06/16');
```

Will throw the error. When using `DATETIME` `yyyyMMdd` is the **ONLY** culture invariant datetime format, when using `DATE` `yyyy-MM-dd` will also work.

---

**EDIT**

It is only when creating [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ffc1/3) to demonstrate the method of casting to date, that I have noticed that in your example the date you are searching for is the 16th June 1962, yet the record you are looking for is the 15th June 1962. It does not matter how many casts and conversions you do, the 15th June will never be the 16th, whatever time of day.

Comment: CONVERT(DATE, BirthDate) = CONVERT(DATE, '1962-06-16') didn't work for me. Will try SET DATEFORMAT DMY; option.

Comment: After some effort and running into this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500563/why-ss-round-to-nearest-minute-that-will-change-day?rq=1. I got it working with the following condition: WHERE
convert(DATE, BirthDate) >= Convert(DATE, '1962/06/15')
AND convert(DATE, BirthDate) < Convert(DATE, '1962/06/16'). Is there a less verbose way this can be achievd I wonder